# I've created a user but it hasn't been connected to my other stackexchange profiles

Tags: discussion, users

As far as I remember for the other sites I didn't have to enter my name, email address and other data. They were picked up from my stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Your account is [associated fine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/16562/user16562?tab=accounts). There's an issue with creating new accounts that prevented your information from getting copied though; it's been reported on [the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125417/when-i-logged-in-to-the-graphic-design-beta-site-with-my-openid-why-didnt-any). For now, you should be able to go to [your accounts tab on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32090/boris-pavlovic?tab=accounts) and click the "copy profile" button at the bottom to copy your SO profile to all sites, including UL:

[Screenshot of the button http://so.mrozekma.com/copy-profile.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/copy-profile.png)

---

**Edit**: This is [fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125477/145982)